# Clear GPG Cache/Password after Encryption in Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, bash, security, terminal, gnupg

I am very annoyed with the GPG encryption process in the Linux terminal, I encrypt files with GPG from the terminal with the following command:

`gpg --output file_out --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 file_in`

This command has been recommended here since GPG is a reliable encryption package.

The problem is that after enter the password and encrypt the file, the password doesn't get deleted. So anyone who has access to the PC can decrypt this file, and it doesn't get deleted only after I restart the computer.

So if I enter the decryption command right after:
`gpg --output file_in --decrypt file_out`

It will give this message

```
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
```

And it will decrypt this automatically. So the password is stored somewhere and it doesn't get deleted until I restart the computer.

**Is there any way to clear/wipe the password right after the encryption is finished?**

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passphrase is saved by `gpg-agent`. GPG tools like `gpg` start it automatically.

Use [`gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html#Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT) to stop agent.

Answer (score 11):

Simply reloading `gpg-agent` (instead of killing it) clears its passphrase cache. It exists different methods to reload `gpg-agent`:

- `echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent`
- `gpgconf --reload gpg-agent`
- `pkill -SIGHUP gpg-agent`

Comment: This is a way better solution than the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can add `--no-symkey-cache` option, which disable the passphrase cache used for symmetrical encryption and decryption.

`gpg --no-symkey-cache --output file_out --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 file_in`

something like that.